# Dynamic Facebook share button via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

HTML:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="sonuc">        
    <span>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>  
  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">        
    <span class="field-content"><a href="#" class="share">Share</a></span>  
  </div>  <div class="sonucbg"></div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="sonuc">        
    <span>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2222</span>  
  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">        
    <span class="field-content"><a href="#" class="share">Share</a></span>  
  </div>  <div class="sonucbg"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#share').click(function() {

  var product_name = jQuery(".sonuc span").html();

  FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: product_name,
  }, function(response) {
    if(response && response.post_id){}
    else{}
  });
});
```

When I click my `.share` button, get popup, its OK. But I want, e.g. click first share button, get that text.

How can I do it?

Comment: Really not clear what your objective is. Get what text and do what with it?

Comment: Why? I want seperate my divs via this.

Comment: Let me rephrase....please explain problem in more detail

Comment: If I click first div, get text 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' But if I click second div, get this text 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2222'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to isolate the instance of `.sonuc span` within the `views-row` instance based on which button was clicked

Try this:

```
$('.share').click(function() {    
  var product_name = $(this).closest('.views-row').find(".sonuc span").html();
  /* FB code */
});
```

What you currently have will always get the html from the first `.sonic` contained in the page